# Using Pixel and Tonic Assets 2 for websites with lots of images

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic

Simple question here! I'm using Assets on every site but I found the last version very slow when browsing files, creating folders etc. etc. so what do you use in large siteswith lots of images?

(also notice that I only use Mediatemple DV 1GB - one server for one website!)

Thanks!
Francesco

Comment: How many images are we talking about?

Comment: For example lets say 3000 images some 1000 high resolution

Comment: Is this the only site you've used Assets on with so many images? As in, do you think it might be an issue with that version of Assets or just that Assets doesn't handle that many images well?

Comment: I noticed the slowdown with the latest version, while the previous one was faster

Answer (score 1):

I use Assets for most clients since it is so much easier for them to use. Some them have (what I would consider) a lot of images and I haven't heard of any issues.